# C# MessageBox shown twice

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several groupboxes on a windows form with a check box, number picker & combo box.  If the check box is not selected I want the other elements disabled.  I've disabled everything but the checkboxes on load and then coded 'if/else' criteria on the CheckedChanged event and all works fine.  However a couple of group boxes are dependent on another condition from an earlier form.  So if a user tries to select that checkbox but the condition isn't valid, I want to display a message, uncheck the checkbox and disable the other elements in the groupbox until the user goes back and changes the condition ... or just accepts things as they are and moves on.  All works pretty much as expected, except the message box is displayed twice, i.e. displayed, cancel out, displayed again ... I'm thinking once when the box is checked and again when it's unchecked (if I just leave it checked, but disabled, the message is only shown once, but that's kind of ugly. ;-(  Is there a better way to do this?

```
private void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(var1 == "YES")
        {
            if (checkbox1.Checked)
            {
                numbox.Enabled = true;
                combobox1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                numbox.Enabled = false;
                combobox1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Required condition is not YES");
            checkbox1.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Changing the check mark will run that event again.  You need a variable that says "don't run this code while I change the check mark", or remove and add the event handlers.

Comment: Create intuitive and easy-to-use UI instead.  var1 should be a property, its setter should set the checkbox1.Enabled property.  And you no longer have a good reason to tell the user he's a dummy.

Answer (score 2):

Like @LarsTech said ... you are calling your event twice.
Here is a possible workaround. Just remove your event at the beginning of your methode. In the end ... add it again.

```
private void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkbox1.CheckChanged -= checkbox1_CheckedChanged;
        if(var1 == "YES")
        {
            if (checkbox1.Checked)
            {
                numbox.Enabled = true;
                combobox1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                numbox.Enabled = false;
                combobox1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Required condition is not YES");
            checkbox1.Checked = false;
        }
        checkbox1.CheckChanged += checkbox1_CheckedChanged;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove and readd the event handler as in the below example.

```
 else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Required condition is not YES");
            checkbox1.CheckedChanged -= checkbox1_CheckedChanged;
            checkbox1.Checked = false;
            checkbox1.CheckedChanged += checkbox1_CheckedChanged;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `checkbox1_CheckedChanged` event you could use the `checkbox1_Click` event to detect the user input. If you change the `checkbox1.Checked` state in your programm, the `checkbox1_Click` event won't be raised.

```
private void checkbox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //your code 
}
```

Comment: `checkbox1_Click` will not raise if the user works with keyboard (focus the checkbox and press space: `checkbox1_CheckedChanged` will raise, `checkbox1_Click` not).

Comment: you could additionally bind the `checkbox1_Click` method to the `KeyPress` event of the checkbox.

Comment: ... and hope we are not forgetting other ways of change the checked state of check box. I prefer the approach suggested in other answer: setting a flag "the code is changing the Checked property" (or similar)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like it is necessary to display the message and uncheck the box if the box is already unchecked...so why not just check whether or not the box is checked before you display the message instead of constantly fiddling with the event registration?

```
private void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(var1 == "YES")
    {
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            numbox.Enabled = true;
            combobox1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            numbox.Enabled = false;
            combobox1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    else if (checkbox1.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Required condition is not YES");
        checkbox1.Checked = false;
    }
}
```